# how to display calculated timedelta as time in python

Tags: python, taskwarrior

I'm calculating time stored in `timewarrior` via [timew-report](https://github.com/lauft/timew-report) python library.

I'm adding up the time, which I'm able to do.  And I'm trying get the total to display in just a number of hours:minutes:seconds, without days.

My script....

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from timewreport.parser import TimeWarriorParser #https://github.com/lauft/timew-report

parser = TimeWarriorParser(sys.stdin)

total = datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
for interval in parser.get_intervals():
    duration = interval.get_duration()
    print(duration)
    total = total + duration
print(total)
```

...works properly, returning:

```
0:01:09
0:06:03
7:00:00
0:12:52
20:00:00
0001-01-02 03:20:04
```

...but instead of showing `0001-01-02 03:20:04` I'd like it to say `27:20:04`.

How do I get it to be formatted like that?

Am I taking the wrong approach by initializing total like `datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `timewarrior`, but you are interested in time durations rather than full timestamps, you probably want to use `datetime.timedelta` objects rather than `datetime.datetime`. It looks like you are starting with a timestamp and adding on a bunch of timedeltas; why not just add up the timedeltas so that you end up with a timedelta, then get the `total_seconds()` and do your own conversion to HH:MM:SS (do the arithmetic).

Comment: awesome!  you're right, `datetime.timedelta` is what I want!  Could you provide an answer?

Comment: Okay, I have done this.

Comment: Do you perhaps a link  to (a git o)f your full code as implemented? I would be interested.

Comment: @a.t. see the answer I just posted with the full script, enjoy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption that `interval.get_duration` is returning a `datetime.timedelta` object each time, you can just add these to an existing `datetime.timedelta` object, and then do the arithmetic to convert to HH:MM:SS format at the end.  (You will need to do your own arithmetic because the default string representation for timedelta will use days and HH:MM:SS if the value exceeds 24 hours, which you don't want.)

For example:

```
import datetime

total = datetime.timedelta(0)
for interval in parser.get_intervals():
    duration = interval.get_duration()
    total += duration

total_secs = int(total.total_seconds())
secs = total_secs % 60
mins = (total_secs // 60) % 60
hours = (total_secs // 3600)

print("{hours}:{mins:02}:{secs:02}".format(hours=hours, mins=mins, secs=secs))
```

Comment: I'm getting "invalid syntax" on the `print(f...)` line

Comment: @alec Okay, I'll change it to a version that will work in older versions of Python.

Comment: @alec Try it now.

Comment: oh was the previous `print()` for python3?  I had this using python 3 earlier today but I stumbled my way over to python2 apparently.

Comment: @alec I think f-strings require python >= 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in this timewarrior report, here's my final working code.  Put this in `scriptname` located in timewarrior extensions directory then invoke like `timew scriptname tagname` to see a timereport showing annotations and total uninvoiced time for a given tag (it can also be used without a tag to display all time entries).

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from timewreport.parser import TimeWarriorParser #https://github.com/lauft/timew-report

parser = TimeWarriorParser(sys.stdin)

total = datetime.timedelta()
tags = ''
for interval in parser.get_intervals():
    tags = interval.get_tags()
    # this report shows only un-invoiced time, so we ignore "invoiced" time entries
    if 'invoiced' not in tags:
        # hide 'client' and 'work' tags since they clutter this report
        if 'clients' in tags:
            tags.remove('clients')
        if 'work' in tags:
            tags.remove('work')
        date = interval.get_start()
        duration = interval.get_duration()
        ant = interval.get_annotation()
        sep = ', '
        taglist = sep.join(tags)
        output = str(date.date()) + ' - ' + str(duration) + ' - ' + taglist
        if ant:
            output += ' ||| ' + str(ant)
        print(output)
        total = total + duration

print('----------------')

# We calculate the time out like this manually because we don't want numbers of hours greater than 24 to be presented as days
total_secs = int(total.total_seconds())
secs = total_secs % 60
mins = (total_secs // 60) % 60
hours = (total_secs // 3600)

# for new versions of python 3.6 and up the following could work
# print(f"{hours}:{mins:02}:{secs:02}")
# but for older python this works...
print("total = {hours}:{mins:02}:{secs:02}".format(hours=hours, mins=mins, secs=secs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `total` seconds to `timedelta` function from `datetime` like below:

```py
total = your_total.timestamp()
total_time = datetime.timedelta(seconds=total) 
str(total_time)
```

Comment: thanks @ahmadgh74 I've seen this elsewhere but not sure how to use it.  I think the other solution is the direction that will work.

Comment: your `total` is datetime and you can get all seconds by `timestamp()` method